# Interview q: Data structure and algorithm for O(1) retrieval of avg. response time in client server architecture

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, client-server

Intv Q:
In a client-server architecture, there are multiple requests from multiple clients to the server. The server should maintain the response times of all the requests in the previous hour. What data structure and algo will be used for this? Also, the average response time needs to be maintained and has to be retrieved in O(1).

My take:
algo: maintain a running mean

```
mean =          mean_prev *n + current_response_time

                -------------------------------
                              n+1


 DS: a set (using order statistic tree).
```

My question is whether there is a better answer. I felt that my answer is very trivial and the answer to the questions(in the interview) before this one and after this one where non trivial.

EDIT:
Based on what amit suggested:

```
cleanup()
    while(queue.front().timestamp-curr_time > 1hr)
        (timestamp,val)=queue.pop();
         sum=sum-val
         n=n-1;

insert(timestamp,value)
    queue.push(timestamp,value);
    sum=sum+val
    n=n+1;
    cleanup();

query_average()
    cleanup();
    return sum/n;
```

And if we can ensure that cleanup() is triggered once every hour or half an hour, then query_average() will not take very long. But if someone were to implement timer trigger for a function call, how would they do it?

Comment: @Nikunj: "interview-question" is a meta tag that doesn't really add anything, and it's been burninated before. Please don't edit posts to re-create it without discussing on Meta first. (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142869/why-was-the-interview-questions-tag-removed )

Comment: @Wooble I didnt know that it had been burinated. My bad. Thanks for informing. Will keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your solution is it only takes the total average since the beginning of time, and not for the last one hour, as you supposed to.

To do so, you need to maintain 2 variables and a *queue* of entries `(timestamp,value)`.

The 2 variables will be `n` (the number of elements that are relevant to the last hours) and `sum` - the sum of the elements from the last hour.

When a new element arrives:

```
queue.add(timestamp,value)
sum = sum + value
n = n+1
```

When you have a query for average:

```
while (queue.front().timestamp > currentTimeAtamp() - 1 hour):
    (timestamp,value) = queue.pop()
    sum = sum - value
    n = n-1
return sum/n
```

Note that the above is still `O(1)` on average, because for every insertion to the queue - you do exactly one deletion. You might add the above loop to the insertion procedure as well.

Comment: You can get O(log n) worst case and O(1) amortized by using binary search and prefix sums to replace the while loop. Not sure about O(1) worst case though